# NameError: name 'X' is not defined but it is

Tags: python, sys

I'm currently working on a project and I keep getting this error when executing a Python script:

```
File "D:\projects\company\spiders\country\spain\cities\runnables\short.py", line 22, in <module>
    soup = get_soup_from_url(url, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'get_soup_from_url' is not defined
```

The function "get_soup_from_url" is getting imported from another file that's located on another directory. In order of giving a minimal reproducible example i made this little project where I'm getting the same error with just two basic scripts. Here are the two scripts:

**short.py**

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('../../../../utils')

from driver import *

print_on_console('Hello world!')
```

**driver.py**

```py
def print_on_console(message):
    print(message)
```

So basically I get this error when trying to import the function "print_on_console" into short.py. The project structure follows this:

```
- spiders
   - country
      - portugal
         - cities
            - runnable
               - short.py
   - utils
      - driver.py
```

I'm sharing this project with other people and they don't have this error with the exact same code, so I guess I missed something when configuring my visual studio code for python but I've been two days searching for what's wrong without finding any solution.

Thanks to anyone who gives me any information in advance.

Comment: The meaning of `sys.path.append('../../../../utils')` depends entirely on what the current working directory is; it may or may not be the directory containing the running script, depending on just how you ran it.  Print out `os.getcwd()` to find out what it is.

Comment: The code should be installed somewhere that is on `sys.path` when the program starts (possibly using `PYTHONPATH`), rather than the script itself assuming it knows where the library is and patching `sys.path` itself.

Comment: @NukeSkull I tested this, and it is definitely about the path. I gave full path to `sys.path.append` and it worked. So your using `..` to back up a folder might not work. Can you give full path and see?

Comment: Hi everyone, when executing the short.py script I do it with "runnable" as working directory @jasonharper. Tried both with `../` and giving the full path but none of them seems to work, I still get the same error. Tried also printing the sys.path and I can see full path is correctly getting saved and when I control+click on it visual studio marks me the folder where driver.py is contained, so I assume it finds the folder correctly, but still getting the error @mmustafaicer

Answer (score 0):

Method `get_soup_from_url` is from another "utils" existing python library.
The simplest way is to check your utils into something else and unique.

If that fixes your problem, try using relative imports to ensure you are importing correct "utils".

Comment: Hi, @K.H., thanks for answering. I tried changing the name of the utils folder into something else (changed it for random letters to make sure it's not another python library) and still got same error. Tried adding the full path to sys.path and it seems to add it right, when I print it and control+click on the path visual studio marks me the folder where driver.py is located, so I guess it's getting my folder and not another library from python, although it still gives me same error

Answer (score 0):

`sys.path.append('../../../../utils')` this does not point to the desired folder. `sys.path` is a list of folders/directories where the Python interpreter searches for modules. So it is not aware of where your working directory is or where does this Python file runs. It is just a **regular list** that you can append anything to it.

So, what your command does is it adds `'../../../../utils'` to the end of `sys.path`.

You can check this by running `print(sys.path)` after this line. You will see something like this at the end:

```
, '../../../../utils']
```

instead you should point the full path to it as an argument

try this:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

p = str(Path(__file__).parents[4]) #4 folders up

sys.path.append(p + '\\utils')

from driver import *

print_on_console('Hello world!')
```

output:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\dasani\Sandbox\trash\test_delete> & C:/Users/dasani/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/dasani/Sandbox/trash/test_delete/country/spain/contrataciondelestado/runnable/short.py
Hello world!
```

Comment: Hi @mmustafaicer, thanks for answering. Tried your solution but I'm still getting the same error message. Here's a link to a screenshot in case it helps knowing what is happening [link](https://imgur.com/a/I28TPLU). Also tried hardcoding the full path but I got same output. As you can see in the screenshot the path is correctly added to the sys.path, and when I control+click on it visual studio marks me the folder where driver.py is located, so I don't understand why the method is not getting imported